A man who could cause disasters and a psychiatrist
I am looking for a show about a man who was seeing a psychiatrist, and explaining to this  psychiatrist that he could cause disasters.  The psychiatrist tells him that it is not true. Near the end the man causes a plane to start to crash to convince the psychiatrist, and I think the psychiatrist kills him to save the plane.  Maybe in the 60s or 70s?  

Would that be "The Medusa Touch" (1978) with Richard Burton? See a clip here.


That's what I thought at first, too (after reading the question title), but the content doesn't really fit (yet I was sure somebody else would still pick it up).

It's possible, as I remember it quite vaguely. But I'm pretty positive about the final scenes, though: him being on life support, the doctor/psychiatrist finally starting accepting that the threat is real, bashing his head to save the plane,... It is at least alike.

Thank-you, this is the one I had in mind--and indeed I recalled it poorly.  Thank-you very much!

The Night Visions episode Patterns, (2002), was similar, though the character wasn't causing disasters, he was preventing them with his obsessive-compulsive rituals.  From Yahoo Answers:

He claims his patterns hold everything together: keeping ties the same
  color and planes in the air. In short, he has a contract with God.
  Chritchley doesn't believe him and drugs him, and strange things start
  to happen. People kill themselves, fish drop out of the sky, and
  firemen start fires. Chritchley insists Martin teach him the patterns
  which he refuses to do, telling the doctor that now he has the
  contract.

The episode is on Youtube.  This link will take you to the scene near the end involving the plane.
